# Remove property from object on AngularJS $resource update/save

Tags: angularjs

I have a issue with AngularJS $resource. My rest API returns properties which is read only and cannot be saved. When I update the resource Angular sends back the entire object which is not what I want. Is there a way to remove spesific properties from the object before a save or update command?

My resource is as follows.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('PressureSensorService', function ($resource, RestConfigService) {
        return $resource(RestConfigService.baseUrl + '/pressure_sensors/:pressure_sensorId',{pressure_sensorId: "@id"},
            {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have opted not to use an Angular resource, but using Restangular which give me a lot more control.